# ManyToMany Database With Three Models

Tags: c#

I have more of a theoretical question. I have three Models. Employee, Commission and Position. Currently I created a ManyToMany relationship database EmployeeCommission (an Employee has many Commissions and Commissions have many Employees) but I also need to add Position to the relationship which would make that Commissions have many Employees that can have many Positions and so on. (Same employee can have different positions in different commissions).

How do I go about this? I know that ManyToMany relationship can only be between to models, so how do I create a ManyToMany database between three models?
Here's my Models, but I don't think you'll need them, but just for general information.

```
public class Employee
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
  public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
public class Commission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class Position
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Note: I am using CodeFirst approach.

Comment: This is completely unrelated to ASP.NET (tags removed), please tag the technologies you are actually using (EF/LinQ to SQL/ADO.NET) and server (SQL Server/Oracle/MySQL)

Comment: What is the data Base and technology are you using?

Comment: Are you asking how my database looks like? I'm using Microsoft SQL Server and CodeFirst approach in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can View thisexample to do that:

```
    public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class UserAccount
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
    .HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.AccountId });

modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.User)
    .WithMany(e => e.UserAccounts)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);

modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Account)
    .WithMany(e => e.UserAccounts)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.AccountId);

modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Role)
    .WithMany(e => e.UserAccounts)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.RoleId);
```

You can create a new UserAccount in a several ways.

Comment: This doesn't help with the Database question. How do I write the database with these three models and all of them having many to many relationships between each other?